# Is it possible to check if a class calls a specific method?

Tags: python, introspection

I have code in which all classes that call a specific function need to be in a dictionary. Something like this:

```
import random

# Anna calls foo via bar
# Bob re-defines foo, but does not call foo
# Charlie calls foo via baz
# David inherits baz from Charlie which calls foo. And David does not re-define baz.
callsfoo_classname2class = {'Anna': Anna, 'Charlie': Charlie, 'David': David}


class Human:
    def foo(self):
        ...


class Anna:
    def bar(self):
        self.foo()


class Bob:
    def foo(self):
        ...


def Charlie:
    def baz(self):
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            self.foo()


def David:
    ...
```

I want to write a test that checks if `callsfoo_classname2class` has all required keys. I can get a list of all candidate classes (inheriting from `Human`). This is a superset of what I want. Is it possible to see if anywhere in the source code of a given class is a call to a specific method of that class?

I know for sure that we don't do anything with `getattr` / `setattr` in those classes. If those methods are called, they are called as `self.foo()`

Comment: Why do you want a dictionary like this? What problem is the dictionary meant to solve? The best solution to that problem is probably not what you're describing in this question.

Comment: @kaya3 I have a dictionary like this in a more complex system. I don't want to change that system now, but I want to improve tests coverage to prevent user errors.

Comment: OK, and what is the harm if your dictionary contains all of the candidate classes instead of just the ones which might call the `foo` method?